# CSS position absolute with height in %

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

I'm learning HTML/CSS and wanted to understand absolute positioning. I made a very simple structure where I want main container to have 100% width and height with relative position. div logo should have an absolute position given in %.

The problem is that main container needs height value in pixels, that time I can use top property for logo div in %. Otherwise it doesn't work, and I want to understand why.

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.main-container {
  background-color:grey;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  position:relative;
}
.logo {
  background-color:yellow;
  top:10%;
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    Main container
    <div class="logo">
      logo
      </div>  
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: your code is working fine (the answer below is incorrect). The issue is that 10% of a small height is a small value so your element won't move a lot. Check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/tLw3jhfs/

Comment: @Temani Afif could you please explain me also why main container background color (grey) doesn't take up all page space, but just a single line? See here https://imgur.com/a/NxHsmnc